# Rename .pgsql to .sql files recursively with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I'm attempting to rename multiple files in a github repo directory on windows 10 pro

The file extensions are ".pgsql" (old) and ".sql" (rename to)

I'm using vscode (latest) and python 3.7 (latest)

I can do it, one folder at a time, but whenever I have tried any recursive directory code I've looked up on here I cant get it to work.

Currently working single directory only

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

folder = 'C:/Users/YOURPATHHERE'
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
       infilename = os.path.join(folder,filename)
       if not os.path.isfile(infilename): continue
       oldbase = os.path.splitext(filename)
       newname = infilename.replace('.pgsql', '.sql')
       output = os.rename(infilename, newname)
```

I'd like to have it recursively start in a directory and change only the file extensions specified to .sql in all sub directories as well on windows, for example

```py
folder = 'C:/Users/username/github/POSTGRESQL-QUERY/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.walk()`,

```
import os

folder = 'C:/Users/YOURPATHHERE'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in files: 
        infilename = os.path.join(root,filename)
        newname = infilename.replace('.pgsql', '.sql')
        output = os.rename(infilename, newname)
```

Comment: This worked great, I modified it slightly to exclude some directories and pull the dir_exclude and dir_startdir from modular files, so I can reuse them

[GitHub Repo Link](https://github.com/talltechy/Python-Scripts/blob/master/Windows/rename_files_in_folder.py)